# Get filename from Edit text in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to write the file name in the gui edit text and save edit text as my filename. Than I could be able to save filename as I wish. For instance; My file is an Neural network file which could be save as *.mat file; here is my code

```
        %network_name is my edit text 
        name = get(handles.network_name,'string');
        name = net;
        save name
```

But it doesn't work I can't manage file name from edit text :(

It saves as name that l wrote next to save (name.mat). Thanks for your any answer...

Answer (score 1):

Why `name = net;`?

That aside, if you want to pass the filename as a variable to the `save` function, you need to use this syntax instead:

```
save(name)
```

`save name` is the "command form", and `save('name')` is the corresponding "function form". As you can see you can only give string inputs when using command form, whilst you actually want to pass a variable.

To conclude: if you are passing variables to a function, use function form.

If you want to save particular variables, use:

```
save(name,'net');
```

Note that `name` (which we want to be the string contained in the variable) isn't in quotes and `net` (the name of the variable we want to save) is.

---

A warning about this is actually buried in the documentation for `save`.

> Do not use command form when any of the inputs, such as filename,
>   are variables.

Comment: Clarified a bit what exactly the difference is between functional and command form.

Comment: Define "didn't work".  You probably want to put a debug point in and step through, make sure that `name` is the string you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have tried it before and it didn't work:( I want to save my Neural Network file name by getting from text file. And name = net; is mean I copied my net to name. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Well, that's not how it works.  name = net makes `name` a copy of `net`, it erases the string! See edit.

Comment: Yes exactly it does. And is there any way to manage filename from edit text?

Comment: @meryem It looks like the answer has been updated to show how you can specify both the filename and the variablename. If it is still not ok, please be more descriptive about what you have and what you want.

Comment: % Train the Network
%default Levenverg-Marquardt algorithm(trainlm) for training
            [net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
            %Test the Network
            outputs = net(inputs);
            errors = gsubtract(outputs,targets);
            perf = perform(net,targets,outputs);
            perfnum = num2str(perf);
            set(handles.performance,'string',perfnum);
            Siemens = net;
            save Siemens 
load Siemens
load in_matrix
inputs = transpose(in_matrix);
output_values = sim(Siemens,inputs);

Comment: Here is part of code which l train my net than I want to save my train  network as an *.mat file with the name that l wrote in edit text but I can not figure out to give a filename. Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
save name
```

will save all of the variables in your workspace to a *.mat file called 'name'

Also your code is basically overwriting itself, line 2 sets the variable `name` to be a string, but then line 3 writes some data `net` to that variable.

I'm a little confused as to exactly what you want but I think you want to save the variable `net` to a mat file with the name that you read in the string from `get(handles.network_name,'string')`

If that is what you want to do then its just

```
save(get(handles.network_name,'string'), net)
```

If you want to save all the open variabile in the workspace then its just

```
save(get(handles.network_name,'string'))
```

Comment: ??? Error using ==> save
Argument must contain a string.

Error in ==> NeuralNetwork>CreateNetwork_Callback at 613
            save(get(handles.network_name,'string'),net);

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});
when I use this line it gives me this error

Comment: save(get(handles.network_name,'string')) this line may could help me sometimes it happens and can't figure with such easy things. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is when I save this with save(get(handles.network_name,'string')) I can't reach net file. It saves all the variables in one file and is there a way to reach specific variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to do well enough. You need to either paste more of your code or be much more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your attention finally I have done with it :)